# Does a switch schematic symbol have a conventional "polarity"?

Tags: schematics, diagram, symbol, standard

I'm studying Rudy Severns eBook [*Snubber Circuits for Power Electronics*](http://www.snubberdesign.com/snubber-book.html); great read by the way.

In it he has the following figure, notice the phrase in the caption "including voltage and polarity conventions":

[image]

Should I take this to mean that there is a conventional orientation for the "opening" and "hinge", so to speak, of the switch symbol in a schematic? At least in a DC context where current would only be flowing the one direction?

I hadn't encountered that before and kind of have my doubts, but my engineering mind would like a convention that leads to a one-and-only-one right way to orient a symbol that otherwise has a degree of freedom to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No a switch doesn't normally have polarity, but when you implement a switch with semiconductors you have to worry whether they are one-quadrant, two-quadrant or four-quadrant, depending on what *the rest of your circuit* requires/imposes in terms of current and voltage. For example a BJT is good a 1st quadrant (or 3rd quadrant) switch and a diode as a 2nd quadrant (or 4th quadrant) switch. A MOSFET is good as two-quadrant switch if well chosen (body diode considerations). A good presentation of that topic is in [Erickson's course](https://youtu.be/Bqf9EOFLrco?list=PLnDj54bZDNd5R3xCVR4u5DG4kGUvK_cv9&t=272).

Comment: Super helpful link, thanks for that, I think I'm going to watch that whole series :)  Based on your response, I'm now interpreting that phrase in Rudy's book to mean something like: "... the polarity conventions of the voltage dropped across the switch, based on the direction of current flow, regardless of the orientation in which you draw the switch 'opening' and 'hinge'".

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen or used any convention for polarity or current direction on a mechanical switch or relay contact.

You may have to pay attention to polarity or current direction with solid-state relays or transistor switching schemes.

It is generally recommended that switches be placed in the "hot" wire feeding a load, rather than on the ground side of the load.